# Scrapy doesn't return meta property tag

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm currently trying to retrieve a meta property tag along with some values from the script tag. The values from the script tag work just fine. I have a problem only with the meta property tag. I've written an xpath for it, for it seems it doesn't work because it return `"None"`.
The line I've talking about is:

```
name = response.xpath("//meta[@name='og:country-name']/@content").extract_first()
```

The meta property from the page is:

```
<meta property="og:country-name" content="al">
```

I want to retrieve the content inside it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attribute is not a `name`, but `property`, so just replace

```
"//meta[@name='og:country-name']/@content"
```

with

```
"//meta[@property='og:country-name']/@content"
```